# Embed Smart Capture Forms on multiple pages

Tags: marketing-cloud, smart-capture

I've not used Smart Capture forms before, but I've been tasked with replacing all the 'contact us' forms on the website with them. There are at least 30 different pages on the website with 'contact us' webforms going to the old system at the moment. Do I need to build 30+ different smart capture forms, or if I build one can I embed that same code on as many pages as I like? They all request the same information and will all be going to the same Data extension.

Answer (score 0):

One smart capture form is enough since you are using the same data extension for all pages.